# prosilica camera_info frame_id in gazebo off?

Tags: gazebo

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The frame_id in the camera_info topic in gazebo (diamondback) is high_def_frame. I believe it should be high_def_optical_frame instead, as it is on the real PR2.

Chris

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/11092/prosilica-camera_info-frame_id-in-gazebo-off?/) by [Chris](https://answers.ros.org/users/1026/chris/) on ROS Answers with karma: 11 on 2011-09-01

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [hsu](https://answers.ros.org/users/91/hsu/) on 2011-09-01**:
Unfortunately, all urdf optical frames in pr2 predates rep 103, hence, they are all *_optical_frame.  Might not be worth the effort to switch all of them at this point.

**Comment by [joq](https://answers.ros.org/users/25/joq/) on 2011-09-01**:
Are you sure it's not `high_def_frame_optical`? That would follow REP 103.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Yes, you've caught a typo, please see [ticket/patch](https://code.ros.org/trac/wg-ros-pkg/ticket/5145), awaiting next patch release for diamondback.  Thanks.

---

Originally posted by [hsu](https://answers.ros.org/users/91/hsu/) with karma: 5780 on 2011-09-01

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0